# invokeSelector:withObject: crashes in Release

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have code

```objective-c
[target invokeSelector:handler.successAction withObject:object];
```

It may call some methods. With object or without. It perfectly works in Debug, but crashes in Release:

```
Nov 20 21:55:13 efpies project[7202] <Warning>: >>>> selector: successfulLogin
Nov 20 21:55:13 efpies project[7202] <Warning>: >>>> target: <AppDelegate: 0x1f595a90>
Nov 20 21:55:13 efpies project[7202] <Warning>: >>>> object: <7b226d65 73736167 65223a22 5c753034 31325c75 30343435 5c753034 33655c75 30343334 205c7530 3434305c 75303433 305c7530 3433375c 75303434 305c7530 3433355c 75303434 385c7530 3433355c 75303433 64227d> NSConcreteMutableData
Nov 20 21:55:13 efpies project[7202] <Error>: -[AppDelegate invokeSelector:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f595a90

Nov 20 21:56:12 efpies project[7205] <Warning>: >>>> selector: driversUpdated:
Nov 20 21:56:12 efpies project[7205] <Warning>: >>>> target: <DriversList: 0x1cd5ffd0>
Nov 20 21:56:12 efpies project[7205] <Warning>: >>>> object: (
    ) __NSArrayM
Nov 20 21:56:12 efpies project[7205] <Error>: -[DriversList invokeSelector:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd5ffd0
```

Those methods are available (and even presented in header file). What's wrong? The data and objects are 100% correct

Comment: Use [target performSelector:handler.successAction]; That is the way to do this in cocoa touch since NSObject will handle this for you. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:

Comment: @ACB: I'm fairly sure that `handler.successAction` may already be a `SEL`, so the proper invocation would be `[target performSelector:handler.successAction withObject:object]`.

Comment: @efpies: Where is `-invokeSelector:withObject:` defined? I don't see it on NSObject; usually people wanting to do what you're doing will use the similarly-named method `-performSelector:withObject:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, `invokeSelector:withObject:` is a category method in the static library. Categories from a static library don't load automatically so you should write

`-force_load $(BUILD_ROOT)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/lib_name.a`

to the `Other linker flag` field in target's `Build settings` if it compiles as dependency for the target.

Comment: But why are you using this category method when performSelector is already provided by NSObject protocol? How is it helpful?

Comment: @ACB `performSelector` can throw a warning about possible leaks. For example, you call `performSelector` for object of type `id`. Because the compiler doesn't know if there such selector (type is unknown when compiling). To shut it up and not to write `pragma`s in every place, the wrapper had been written. It just wraps `performSelector` with `#pragma clang diagnostic push`-`#pragma clang diagnostic pop` and has an instruction inside: `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"`. But now we should be sure to call proper selectors in a random object.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[target performSelector:handler.successAction withObject:object];
```

That is the way to do this in cocoa-touch since `NSObject` will handle this for you. 
Check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject) for more details.